# UIImagePicker and UIImage size

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I have an UIImagePickerViewController and I'm saving my image to my app just with *UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage* and :

```
[self.fileManager createFileAtPath:aPath contents:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.f) attributes:nil];
```

Result :

- original image from Photo.app -> 2.2 Mo
- new saved image from my app -> 5.3 Mo with JPEG representation & 10.8 Mo with PNG representation !

So my question is quite simple : why ? And how to reach the Photo.app size ?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Hi @Pierre I've got the same problem. After 3 days of searching online, I couldn't found an explanation or solution. Have you solved it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you probably know, the second parameter passed in UIImageJPEGRepresentation defines the compression quality (1 being the highest). Because the image is broken down back to basic data and then re-compressed (jpeg is a compressed image format), the result may be worse compression (larger file) and of course the image quality will not get any better. Try lowering the parameter to something in between 0.0 and 1.0 and see when you get the best match in file size (Will be unique for each image processed, so try and find a good value in the middle).

Comment: So Apple is re-compressing images from Photo.app ? That means they have two versions of a photo I'm taking : one with no compression and one with compression (for displaying). And when I'm choosing one photo from my pick, they give me the one without compression ? That's weird no ?

Comment: All I'm saying is that the UIImage being returned as the UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage is not the equivalent of the stored image on the device, at least not in file size. The only valid explanation for this is difference in compression. Indeed weird, but I have no other idea as to why this would happen.